# Is there any tool/website where I can read Haskell source code with the Haddock rendered?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I'd like to read the source code for a library ([example](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/src/Data-Either.html#either)), but with the Haddock comments rendered pretty ([example](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Prelude.html#g:2)) . http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs has both of these views, but doesn't combine them together.

Has anyone made a UI to view these together? It would basically be the rendered view, but with the source code for each function/class/whatever inserted directly below each rendered doc item.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking, but there is a "Source" link next to all the definitions which (should) bring you to the line of code where the corresponding definition occurs.

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to get the linked source on the same page. If Haddock emits end tags for each entity (besides the start tags that `Source` links to), then one could use AJAX and DOM manipulation to merge the two views.

Comment: You could duplicate any non-type-signature code, prepending at the first non-whitespace with `-- >` to mark it up as example code, and re-run haddock on it, but maybe you weren't after an offline solution.

Comment: @chunksOf50 nice idea, I might try that!